# External Javascript will execute outside div

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a function loja() in an external js. In another html file, at the end of the file I have linked it to the external js and then at the body of the html file I have created a div and onclick it will call the function loja(). It all works well but the thing is that the javascript function is not loaded inside the div but at the end of the page.Can you help me out?
This is from html file.

```
<div class="section-title" onclick="loja()">Luaj
            </div>
```

This one is the javascript file.

```
  // Create our 'main' state that will contain the game


function loja(){
var mainState = {
   preload: function() { 
    game.load.image('bird', 'assets/car.png'); 
    game.load.image('pipe', 'assets/pipe.png');
    game.load.audio('jump', 'assets/jump.wav'); 
    game.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png'); 
},




create: function() { 
   game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 1000, 600, 'background'); 


    // Set the physics system
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    // Display the bird at the position x=100 and y=245
    this.bird = game.add.sprite(100, 245, 'bird');

    // Add physics to the bird
    // Needed for: movements, gravity, collisions, etc.
    game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bird);

    // Add gravity to the bird to make it fall
    this.bird.body.gravity.y = 1000;  

    // Call the 'jump' function when the spacekey is hit
    var spaceKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(
                    Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
    spaceKey.onDown.add(this.jump, this);  


    // Create an empty group
this.pipes = game.add.group();   

this.timer = game.time.events.loop(1500, this.addRowOfPipes, this);


this.score = 0;
this.labelScore = game.add.text(20, 20, "0", 
    { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff" });

     // Move the anchor to the left and downward
this.bird.anchor.setTo(-0.2, 0.5);   

this.jumpSound = game.add.audio('jump'); 

},





update: function() {
    // If the bird is out of the screen (too high or too low)
    // Call the 'restartGame' function
    if (this.bird.y < 0 || this.bird.y > 490)
        this.restartGame();

   game.physics.arcade.overlap(
    this.bird, this.pipes, this.hitPipe, null, this); 
    if (this.bird.angle < 20)
    this.bird.angle += 1; 
},




// Make the bird jump 
jump: function() {
    // Add a vertical velocity to the bird
    this.bird.body.velocity.y = -300;

    // Create an animation on the bird
var animation = game.add.tween(this.bird);

// Change the angle of the bird to -20° in 100 milliseconds
animation.to({angle: -20}, 100);

// And start the animation
animation.start(); 

if (this.bird.alive == false)
    return; 

    this.jumpSound.play();  
},

// Restart the game
restartGame: function() {
    // Start the 'main' state, which restarts the game
    game.state.start('main');
},


addOnePipe: function(x, y) {
    // Create a pipe at the position x and y
    var pipe = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'pipe');

    // Add the pipe to our previously created group
    this.pipes.add(pipe);

    // Enable physics on the pipe 
    game.physics.arcade.enable(pipe);

    // Add velocity to the pipe to make it move left
    pipe.body.velocity.x = -200; 

    // Automatically kill the pipe when it's no longer visible 
    pipe.checkWorldBounds = true;
    pipe.outOfBoundsKill = true;
},



addRowOfPipes: function() {
    // Randomly pick a number between 1 and 5
    // This will be the hole position
    var hole = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

    // Add the 6 pipes 
    // With one big hole at position 'hole' and 'hole + 1'
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (i != hole && i != hole + 1) 
            this.addOnePipe(400, i * 60 + 10); 

    this.score += 1;
this.labelScore.text = this.score;          
},

hitPipe: function() {
    // If the bird has already hit a pipe, do nothing
    // It means the bird is already falling off the screen
    if (this.bird.alive == false)
        return;

    // Set the alive property of the bird to false
    this.bird.alive = false;

    // Prevent new pipes from appearing
    game.time.events.remove(this.timer);

    // Go through all the pipes, and stop their movement
    this.pipes.forEach(function(p){
        p.body.velocity.x = 0;
    }, this);
},
};
// Initialize Phaser, and create a 400px by 490px game
var game = new Phaser.Game(600, 800);

// Add the 'mainState' and call it 'main'
game.state.add('main', mainState); 

// Start the state to actually start the game
game.state.start('main');
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you also tell us what the problem precisely is? Like why do you want that. Like @FrankerZ said, we can't help unless we have the min info.

Comment: The external js file is a game and I want it to show at a specific place in my html page. Thats why I want to place it inside a div. But as I said it executes at the end of the file and I dont know how to make it show inside that div

Comment: Yeah but what's the problem? Where js file is placed depends on render path and optimization. Usually, js files get an element from the DOM and perform operations on it. Where they are placed shouldn't change what operations they perform on the model. You probably need to upload the file (or a part) and explain in more detail.

Comment: I edited the question and uploaded the code. I dont know how to execute that function to appear inside that div and not at the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

Where javascript code appears in your page in this case seems out of point. 
You linked it at the end of file? Than it will appear at the end of file.

What I understand you want is your code to interact with some part of a html file structure, called DOM, some DIV tag in particular.

You need to use Javascript to interact with that DIV node. Probably to render your game inside of it.

In your JS file I only see definition and some method calls. I cant see part that would render some content into DOM.

Summarizing: place where your javascript methods definitions are it not the same place where effects of execution of those methods will appear.

Comment: I also tried to link it inside the div but it still appeared at the end of the page

Comment: Where you link it, will not change the outcome of the code your JS file contains. 
Dont get me wrong but you seem to not understand how javascript executes.

Comment: Even if that code will get inserted into div, it doesnt mean your game will appear in that div. Only the code responsible for rendering the game will be there. 
It s like you would like to take the code of Tetris or Quake or any other game, copy it to some text editor and expect that it will be playable **in that text editor**. 
It doesnt work like that.

Comment: You need some code that will attach your rendered game inside of that div. 
Something like `document.getElementByClassName("section-title").appendChild($yourGame)`. 
That is very abstract assumption not the usable code, but maybe will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement an open-source Phaser game (https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.4.4/src/core/Game.js)

Since your issue is with functionality regarding that framework, that should be your starting place for information. Also you shouldn't leave out important information like any framework you're using when asking for help (especially since in this case the issue is only that you're not using the it properly).

If you look at the fourth parameter it actually allows you to specify a DOM parent, it accepts either the ID or the element itself. So you could just do something like this after inserting another element in your HTML with the ID `pgame`:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(600, 800, void(0), 'pgame');
```